# Changing Popover view frame on fly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, popover

When a popover is displaying how can I make its size variable depending on condition check? Is this functionality supported or not when working with a popover?

Here is my sample for changing frame size:

```
CGFloat newHeight = 200;
NSRect newFrame  = [parentView frame];
newFrame.size.height = newHeight;

NSView* childView = someView;

[parentView setFrame:newFrame];
[self.view addSubview:childView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `popupwindow.contentViewController` property of the `NSPopover` to a new `NSViewController` with a different-sized view.
That is, resizing the view's frame will only result in weird drawing problems. To get the popover window to change size, the `contentViewController` must be changed.

Ideally, you would set up a new view controller which is essentially a copy of your existing `NSViewController`, but containing a view that is taller/shorter. But in the worst-case scenario, you can do something like this:

```
gPopoverWindow.contentViewController = [[[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"tempNibName" bundle: nil] autorelease];
NSView *v = self.view;
NSRect b = [v frame];
b.size.height += 25;
[v setFrame: b];
gPopoverWindow.contentViewController = self;
```

In my testing, this resulted in the popover beginning a shrink animation (because of being set to the temp view controller), then growing to its new size.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if anything was changed but in 10.9 all you have to do is setContentSize on the popover, e.g.:

```
[popoverView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 581, 581)];
[thePopover setContentSize:popoverView.frame.size];
```